# IntellIJ Maven package capitalizes first letter of resource file names

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, plugins

I have a Maven project in IntelliJ. When I build the project using the Maven "package" function, I get a jar file as expected. IntelliJ also automatically generates a resources folder where you can add resources that Maven will automatically add to the built jar file. In my resources folder, I have a file with the name "plugin.yml". It is important that the entire file name is lowercase. When Maven builds the project, the plugin.yml is added to the jar file, and is located in the correct spot, but the file name gets changed to "Plugin.yml"; the first letter of the file name gets capitalized. The entire filename needs to be lowercase. I am new to Maven so maybe I am missing something, but I have looked online and I can't find anyone with a similar problem.

Here is a picture of my project. As you can see the file is all lowercase:
[Project Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuWpF.png)

Here is a picture of the contents of the built jar file as well as my pom file. As you can see, the file has its first letter capitalized. I know I haven't defined any resources in the pom file, but that was because the plugin.yml was already being exported (just with the wrong name). If defining the plugin.yml as a resource would fix the naming issue, then I can try that: [Jar and pom File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9C1y.png)

I don't know if there is something I need to define in my pom file, but any help would be appreciated.

Text copy of my pom.yml:

```
<groupId>iocia.network.minecraft.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>iskill</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-alpha</version>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!--Spigot API-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: It is not Idea who made this. Look at your `pom.xml`. There something in it that change file name.

Comment: Other option that you already have file with wrong name. Try `mvn clean`

Comment: @talex I edited my original post to include a picture of my pom file (because I can only add 2 picture links, I have combined the jar and pom picture). I have also tried doing `mvn clean`, but that did not work.

Comment: Please post text of your `pom.xml` instead of picture. It is hard to copy-paste picture to my IDE :)

Comment: @talex Updated my post. If you need more information, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I seemed to have fixed my issue. The fix was to add this line into my pom.xml:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Even though I did not originally have this line in my pom, Maven was still building a jar file with all the resource files (despite changing their names). However, now that I added this line, Maven still builds like it did before, except now it does not change the resource file names. Weird.